# Angular Material2 - How to show outside div over the dialog modal?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

Angular Material2 has a dialog component. Basically showing a popup modal. I have another div element (not inside the dialog), which I want to lay it over the dialog.

Is it possible by tweaking the z-index? and if possible how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out by change the z-index. Pls discard

Comment: You can just delete the question if you want.